# is there event or receiver which notify download get completed?

Tags: android, android-intent

while browsing url which download apk file.
Is there any event or receiver that notify us while apk get downloaded?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, your main concern is to install the app programmatically. Write a wrapper to use the `abd` command to install the app.

```
adb install <apkPath>

adb install <packageName>
```

Comment: Thanks @Aashish for anwser. But apk file downloaded from any installed browser in device. So how to know when apk get downloaded? is there any receiver available?

Comment: You need to see if we can capture the notification from browser which says "Your download has been completed".

Comment: yeah you are right!! looking for the same. Is there any event or receiver that notify us while apk get downloaded?

Comment: I have no idea as of now.